# How to execute a validator using the jQuery validation plugin, if some condition is true

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I need to validate certain fields depending on which submit button was clicked, and I have the following code, which is working perfectly.

(I know that there is a 'greater than 3' method already there, but I wanted to check that you could add custom methods)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _btnClicked = "";

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.validator.addMethod('custom', function(value, element, param) { if (param) { return value > 3 } return true; });

            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    input1: { required: function(element) { return _btnClicked == 'div1'; } },
                    input2: { custom: function(element) { return _btnClicked == 'div2'; } } },
                messages: {
                    input1: "Required",
                    input2: "Greater than three"
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

<form id="form1">    
          <div id="div1" class="div1">
            <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" class="div1"/>
            <input id="btn1" name="btn1" type="submit" value="Form 1" class="div1" onclick="_btnClicked = 'div1'; if (!$('#form1').validate().form()) { return false; }" />
          </div>

          <div id="div2" class="div2">
            <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" class="div2"/>
            <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" class="div2"/>
            <input id="btn2" name="btn2" type="submit" value="Form 2" class="div2" onclick="_btnClicked = 'div2'; if (!$('#form1').validate().form()) { return false; }" />
          </div>
     </form>
```

My problem is, what do I do if I wanted to restrict my third input box to a max length of 3?

I can't add this rule, as it clearly isn't being passed the value 3, so it doesn't know what the max length is!

```
input3: { maxlength: function(element) { return _btnClicked == 'div2'; } }
```

Any ideas?

Or better ways of achieving this!?

Comment: What's wrong with `maxlength: 3`?

Comment: I want it so that the validation only fires if a particular button was used to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Define an ignore class (e.g ".ignore") and add that class to those elements when the user clicks "the other" buttons.